# htaccess rule fails in one condition

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am facing some problem on URL rewriting.

I write a rule without base key like below:-

```
RewriteRule ^en/([\w-]+)/([\w-=]+)/([\w-=]+)/([\w-=]+)$ landing.php?n=$1&p=$2&c=$3&k=$4 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-=]+)/([\w-=]+)/([\w-=]+)$ landing.php?n=$1&p=$2&c=$3&k=$4 [QSA,L]
```

I have below URLs:-

```
http://localhost/site/en/video/vi/ca/key //en URL
http://localhost/site/video/vi/ca/key   //normal URL
```

Above both URL is working fine.

But Below URL create problem, this should not work

```
http://localhost/site/en/video/ca/key
```

en URL, working like normal URL. This goes to second rule. Here first rule is not working. GET['n'] shows **n= en** but this **should not work** because **vi** is not present here or this should be **n= video**.

Please check and guide me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `RewriteBase` in the very beginning of you htaccess like below

```
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteRule ^en/(([\w-]+)\/){1,4} landing.php?n=$1&p=$2&c=$3&k=$4 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-=]+)/([\w-=]+)/([\w-=]+)$ landing.php?n=$1&p=$2&c=$3&k=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I am already added Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /site/
Options -Indexes

Comment: Please understand your own rule.

http://localhost/site/en/video/ca/key is definitely gonna match

`RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-=]+)/([\w-=]+)/([\w-=]+)$ landing.php?n=$1&p=$2&c=$3&k=$4 [QSA,L]` because it has 4 matches group. See these are 4 matches 1 = en, 2 = video, 3 = ca,4 = key. So your url is gonna be `http://localhost/site/landing.php?n=en&p=video&c=ca&k=key
The tests are stopped because of the L in your RewriteRule options.` one again 2nd condition is being matched.

Comment: So i changed my answer and the first rule has set as above to fulfil your condition. if you can check now you will see you are getting expected result. Can you please try it ?

Comment: Ok I will try now, i upvote your answer now. Please upvote my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146831/discussion-between-deepak-dholiyan-and-pratik-soni).